# Pointer pointing to itself without typecast?

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, memory-address

I am trying to figure out a way of how to use a global pointer in a local area and then using the pointer. Doing this i realized C89 compiler do not complain on doing so:

```
int* a = NULL;
a = *(&a);
```

Is that even desirable?

Comment: What's supposed to be wrong with this? `&a` is a `int**`, dereferencing it gets you a `int*`.  `a` doesn't end up pointing to itself - the expression is equivalent to `a = a`.

Comment: Isn't it located in sort of.. invalid memory area. It is to itself. There is the problem. Can i threat the pointer as a normal variable without receiving invalid memory errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am trying to figure out a way of how to use a global pointer in a local area and then using the pointer.

This is how:

```
void *ptr = &ptr;
```

This (ab)uses the implicit conversion facility between `void *` and any other object pointer type (`void **` in this case). `ptr` will then contain its own memory address, and you can dereference it:

```
void *qtr = *(void **)ptr;
```

Here, `qtr == ptr` would be true.

I don't think you can do this with any other pointer type, though.

Comment: Oh, how could i assign for example `1` to the pointer and use it?

Comment: @Corelation Like this: `void *p = (void *)1;`, but that won't make the pointer point to itself. Now what do you really want to achieve?

Comment: It is complicated to explain. Something i'm trying to accomplish but i think its not possible.

Comment: @Corelation we could try.

Comment: Actually i did it by myself.

Answer (score 4):

`*(&a)` is in your case equal to simply `a` (you get the address of `a` and then dereference it). So your code does effectively this:

```
a = a;
```

That is completely ok for the type system and just assigns `NULL` to `a`. That's why the compiler doesn't complain.